# Reading in SQL files into Pandas Table

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I have a SQL file titled "DreamMarket2017_product.sql". I believe it's MySQL.

How do I read this file into a Jupyter Notebook using PyMySQL? Or, should I use Psycopg2?

I'm much more familiar w/ Psycopg2 than PyMySQL.

Both PyMySQL and Psycopg request a database name. There is no database. I solely have the files.

Do I need to create a database using a GUI like Pgadmin2 and load those the SQL tables into the newly created database?

Also, I'm still waiting to hear from the university that created the dataset.

Comment: Your .sql file should contain only the query required to extract data from a database, not the actual data.

Comment: Do  I need to create a database then extract the data from the SQL file? How do I create a database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, u need to create a database and load data into table or import table backup u have

```py
connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "dummy",password = "1234",host = "any",port = "1234",database = "demo")
```

Comment: Are my username and password supposed to be what I use to log in to my computer? It's not working.